# PsExec hangs without output when not using -d or -i

Tags: .net, wcf, process, impersonation, psexec

I'm starting **PsExec** inside a WCF web service to **execute a remote command** and **capture it's output**.
It's being run while **impersonating a certain user**.
When trying to run a **non-GUI command** (like ping, tracert..), PsExec just **hangs unless** I use **-d or -i**.
Because I need to get the output, using those parameters is not an option.
**GUI apps** (mspaint, calc, ..) **start** just **fine**.

Any idea **what's going on**?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done enough testing yet, but I just hit this problem myself.
It seems to me that the following link is a confirmation of the same behavior i am seeing.

As soon as I commented out my output, everything started to work again.

http://forum.sysinternals.com/nested-psexec-hangs-if-multiline-command-output_topic21520.html